# using 2 Java classes to display information on 1 XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-appcompat

I am new to programing and I am trying to clean up my main class.
There is just too much going on there.

I was wondering if it is possible to set up a way that 2 classes were to control 1 xml file.

For now I started doing this, but it didnt work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ....SOME CODE....
    getParsha();


  }
}

public void getParsha() {
  new Parsha();
}
```

In new Parsha I had this code:

```
public class Parsha extends AppCompatActivity { 

  Parsha() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


....SOME CODE.....

  }

}
```

I also tried doing this in `onCreate()` and it didnt work.
I am not sure why, is this even allowed to do in Android.

Please Note: I didnt get any error, it simply just didnt process the code, no `Log` or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: i think the problem is because that you called 1 xml twice in 1 java code,
in `MainActivity` you've declared `setcontentview` and you called it again in`getparsha`

Comment: See my post it will help you

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "control 1 xml file".  You don't control xml files in Android.  You can use them to define a display for an Activity.  Only one Activity is in the foreground at a time.  You can have 2 activities with the same display, but it would be unusual and it would be one Activity or the other in the foreground at a time, and running the other would create entirely new display that looks the same.  If you're trying to break down your activity into parts, you would generally break it into functional parts and refactor that into other classes.

Comment: I changed the title of the post. Yes I am trying to display new information in main.xml from 2 classes, is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `Activiy` shoud use `Intent`

Like this

```
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Parsha.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
finish();//if use need to stop use first activity.
```

And then, In your second activity namely Parsha, why you are set content view in inside constructor

You should give this in `onCreate` block only

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Your two activity should be in following structure

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 
        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        ....SOME CODE.... 
getParsha();
         } 

        public void getParsha() { 
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Parsha.class); 
    startActivity(intent);
         }
    }
```

Second Activity

```
    public class Parsha extends AppCompatActivity{ 
        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        ....SOME CODE.... 
         } 
        }
```

Comment: I am not trying to start a new activity, I am trying to display new information on the main xml file from 2 classes

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using xml file in both java files why dont you just make the common variables static and keep the code in Parsha.java, use the class wherever inside onCreate(). The following example might give you a clear idea.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adap;
static ArrayList<String> arr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    new Parsha();
    arr.add("Hello");
    arr.add("There");
    adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
    list.setAdapter(adap);
}
}
```

Parsha.java

```
public class Parsha extends AppCompatActivity{

Parsha(){
    arr.add("This");
    arr.add("Works");
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```